# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to route to homepage if it is a successful login.But I a getting following error:

Error: "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`".

App.js

```js
import Home from './Pages/Home/Home.js';
import Login from "./Pages/Login/Login";
import Profile from "./Pages/Profile/Profile";
import Register from "./Pages/Registration/Registration";
import { useContext,Redirect } from "react";
import {AuthContext} from "./Context/AuthContext";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";


function App() {
  const {user} = useContext(AuthContext);
  console.log(user);
  return (
    <div >
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path ='/'>
            {user ? < Home/> : <Register/>}
          </Route>
          <Route path ='/login'>
          {user ? <Redirect to ="/" /> : < Login/> }
            
          </Route>    
          <Route path ='/profile/:username'>
              < Profile/>
          </Route>
          <Route path ='/register'>
            {user ? <Redirect to ="/" /> : < Register/> }
          </Route>

      </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  )}
export default App;
```

When I try without "{}" :

```js
import AuthContext from "./Context/AuthContext";
```

getting below error:
"Attempted import error: './Context/AuthContext' does not contain a default export (imported as 'AuthContext')."

and also I tried importing using :

```js
var AuthContext = require("./Context/AuthContext.js");
```

Then there is no error but context is not creating ie, user value is undefined.

AuthContext.js

```js
import { createContext } from "react";
import {useReducer} from 'react';
import AuthReducer from './AuthReducer';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
 user : null,
 isFetching : false,
 error : false

}
export const AuthContext = createContext(INITIAL_STATE);

export const AuthContextProvider = ({children})=>{
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AuthReducer, INITIAL_STATE);

    return(
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{
        user : state.user,
        isFetching : state.isFetching,
        error : state.error,
        dispatch,
    }}
    >
        {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
)
}
```

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Comment: `import { AuthContext } from "./Context/AuthContext"`.  But the `return` without a function doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Fix the invalid Javascript inside AuthContext.js, calling return without defining a function is invalid.

Comment: This is the error I am getting then:Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of App". @Keith

Comment: AuthContextProvider is an arrow function @Keith

Comment: Yes, your code indentation didn't help.

Comment: Can you tell what might be the issue ? @Keith

Comment: Where and How are you importing `App` in your code? Make sure it is imported as default.

Comment: in index.js file : 
import App from './App';
import { AuthContextProvider } from "./Context/AuthContext";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <App />

    </AuthContextProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  
  document.getElementById('root')
); @AjeetShah

Comment: I see no error. Can you reproduce the error in a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/ ?